# How to call a NetSuite SuiteScript by SOAP - Ballerina Lang

Tags: soap, netsuite, suitescript, ballerina, oauth-1.0a

I have created a **NetSuite Saved Search** to fetch some data. I have written a SuiteScript to access Saved Search and fetch data. The SuiteScript is also deployed.

I tested the SuiteScript by postman using OAuth 1 authentication flow and its success.

I need to access the same SuiteScript by SOAP request and integrate it using Ballerina.

How can I integrate the OAuth in ballerina and access the SuiteScript?

Comment: What is the Ballerina version that you are using?

Comment: @Buddhi its Swan Lake Alpha 5. I'm using token based authentication which means Oauth 1.0. need to implement this flow using ballerina to access the SuiteScript (Restlets).

Answer (score 2):

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;
import ldclakmal/oauth1;

public function main() returns error? {
    oauth1:ClientOAuthHandler oauthHandler = new({
        signatureMethod: oauth1:HMAC_SHA1,
        consumerKey: "dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",
        consumerSecret: "kd94hf93k423kf44",
        accessToken: "hh5s93j4hdidpola",
        accessTokenSecret: "pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00",
        realm: "Photos",
        nonce: "7d8f3e4a"
    });
    map<string|string[]> securityHeaders = check oauthHandler.getSecurityHeaders("GET", 
        "https://photos.example.net/request?type=jpg&maxsize=10mb");
    final http:Client clientEP = check new("https://photos.example.net");
    json payload = check clientEP->get("/request?type=jpg&maxsize=10mb", securityHeaders);
    io:println(payload);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I referred code of [3]. what should be the parameters for 
getSecurityHeaders(string httpMethod, string url, string? queryParams = ()) ?

Comment: @BuddhikaPriyabhashana it should be the HTTP method you are using for your API call, the complete URL without query params and the query params as a separate parameter, if those are there.

Comment: I have updated the API in a more simplified manner and updated the original answer.